# Azure web.config redirect from one page to another in wordpress

Tags: azure, web-config

I want to redirect a page in Azure web.config with the url:

`http://example.com/Vad+%E4r+V%E4rdskap__1053.html`

to

`http://example.com/what-is-welcoming/`

I'd like it to work for http://**www**.example.com as well.

I tried adding my own rule in web.config with the following code:

```
<rule name="URL1" stopProcessing="true">
     <match url="^Vad\+%E4r\+V%E4rdskap__1053\.html" ignoreCase="true" />
     <action type="Redirect" url="/what-is-welcoming/" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

I also tried without escaping the `+` signs.

Answer (score 1):

There were some issues but I managed to solve the problem.

The first issue was a security setting for `+` signs in URL:s for ISS.

This was solved by using:

```
...
    <security>
        <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true" />
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

The code for the matching and redirect were as follows:

```
<rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="vadarvardskap" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="example.com/Vad+%E4r+V%E4rdskap__1053.html" />
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="www.example.com/Vad+%E4r+V%E4rdskap__1053.html" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://example.com/what-is-welcoming/" redirectType="Permanent"/>
            </rule>
...
```